# Weird problems with reopening Ruby classes

Tags: ruby, classloader, watir

I'm working simultaneously with Watir and Watir-WebDriver and am trying to make them more compatible by reopening some classes and redefining some methods. I ran into weird behavior that I can't explain. I'm trying to understand what's going on.

This is happening with the watir-1.7.1 which is only available on Windows.
Ruby 1.8.7-p330
RUBYOPT=-rubygems

Test 1.

```
require 'watir'

Watir::ElementCollections.class_eval do
  def new_method
  end
end

>ruby open-classes-watir1.rb
open-classes-watir1.rb:3: uninitialized constant Watir::ElementCollections (NameError)
```

Why does Ruby complain about reopening a valid class?

The class in question looks like this:

```
element_collections.rb:

module Watir
   #... 
  class ElementCollections
    include Enumerable
    #...
  end
end
```

But that's not all! Now watch this:

Test 2.

```
require 'watir'

Watir::IE.class_eval do
end

Watir::ElementCollections.class_eval do # Requires the magic incantation above
  def new_method
  end
end

>ruby open-classes-watir2.rb
```

It executes fine now with this black magic spell.
Watir::IE looks like this:

```
ie-class.rb:

module Watir
  class IE
    include WaitHelper
    include Exception
    include Container
    include PageContainer
    #...
  end
end
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a visual aid on this a while back.
http://www.flickr.com/photos/marekj/3615299778/
require 'watir' comes from commonwatir gem
require 'watir/ie' comes from watir gem.
there are two gems at play here.

Comment: I would use require "watir/ie"

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the file `lib/watir/element_collections.rb` which defines `Watir::ElementCollections` is not loaded by calling `require 'watir'`. `lib/watir/ie.rb` requires `lib/watir/core.rb`, which in turn requires `lib/watir/element_collections.rb`.

Try this:

```
require 'watir'
require 'watir/core'

Watir::ElementCollections.class_eval do
  def new_method
  end
end
```

Comment: require 'watir/core' does not fix the problem. I get the same error; I don't know why. require 'watir/element_collections' works.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `require "watir"` doesn't load actually `Watir::IE` yet. `Watir::IE` is loaded by `Kernel.autoload` when doing `Watir::Browser.new`. This is how to make it work:

```
require "watir"
Watir::IE # to trigger autoload

# now Watir::ElementCollections exists
```

Other solution would be to `require "watir/core"` as suggested by Steve.

Comment: Yes, it works, but the code looks hairy. I opted for adding: require 'watir/element_collections'